# Storing jQuery objects using Object Literal pattern

Tags: javascript, jquery, object-literal

Is it possible to store jQuery objects inside Object Literal pattern? In my case inside `config`.

```
var myApp = {
    config: {
        disabledElem: $('.disable')
    },

    init: function () {
        someFunction(this.config.disabledElem);
    }
};

$(function () {
    myApp.init();
});
```

Comment: did you try it? what is the problem you faced?

Comment: as long as the jquery and element has already been loaded by the time this `myApp` is initialized, it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can absolutely store a reference as a value in an object literal.

Perhaps some of your confusion is how you are accessing this value in your `init` function.

Try something like this instead:

```
init: function () {
    someFunction(myApp.config.disabledElem);
}
```

Comment: `this` inside init method is already referring to myApp object

Comment: @A.Wolff but it's not clear from the question how the init function is being invoked so it's not clear what `this` will be during invocation

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink and how can I call the stored object inside the `config` ? For e.g. `disabledInput: disabledElem.closest('input')`

Comment: @Gabriel you mean the dom node? `$('.disable').get(0)`

Comment: @Jonathan.Brink Yes, the DOM node. Currently I have duplicated nodes:
`config: {
        form__internet: $('.form__internet'),
        fi__parent: $('.form__internet').closest('.fieldTypeINPUT')
}`

Comment: When I use it with `this`, `fi__parent: this.closest('.fieldTypeINPUT')`I get the `Cannot read property 'closest' of undefined` error.